# Substract string from url in either jQuery or Php?

Tags: php, jquery

I need to get only the ID of a vimeo URL.

```
http://vimeo.com/68149082
```

I need:

```
68149082
```

In jQuery I am doing this:

```
var videoSpan =  jQuery(".is-expanded").find("span.video");
var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
        'frameborder' : 0,
        'class' : 'embed-responsive-item',
        'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ videoSpan.data("vimeoid")
    });
videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
```

The `vimeoID` is generated by a field which I manually populate by inserting only the ID number. But I need to be able to place the whole vimeo URL `http://vimeo.com/68149082`

Then strip out the URL and only grab the ID for the php output:

```
<span class="video loading clearfix" data-vimeoid="<?php echo the_field('vimeoID') ?>"></span>
```

Therefore I need somehow to be able to strip the ID from `http://vimeo.com/68149082` and place it in `videoSpan.data("vimeoid")`

Comment: `string.split('/').pop()`, same thing in PHP with explode etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = "http://vimeo.com/68149082";
var tokens = url.split("/");
var id = tokens[3];
```

Comment: If you find that this answers your question consider accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: had to wait for few minutes before i could accept it. Thanks

Comment: actually this isn't working. It works if you provide the string as a URl as you did. but that string is coming from videoSpan.data("vimeoid") as you can see in my question

Comment: ok I accept your answer which helped me but my own answer is what really is. It is based on yours with the add ons needed to my specific case. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to substract that information with the `parse_url` function in PHP.

http://www.php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 0):

This is what answered my quetsion. It is based on the accepeted answer which was incomplete for my case but that is what lead me to this solution:

```
var url = $('.video').data("vimeoid");
var tokens = url.split("/");
var id = tokens[3];
var videoSpan =  jQuery(".is-expanded").find("span.video");
var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
  'frameborder' : 0,
  'class' : 'embed-responsive-item',
  'src' : '//player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id + '?autoplay=0&api=1&portrait=0&title=0&byline=0 webkitAllowFullScreen    mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen'
    });
videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
```